# For loop syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a loop to show 5 images using Javascript. I am having some trouble understanding the syntax.

This is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Challenge: Daisy chain</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        var image = $("<img>")
        .attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg')
        .attr('width', '10')
        .attr('alt', 'new name')
        .appendTo('body');

        for(i = 0, i < 5, i++) {
            $(image).appendTo('body');    
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the English issues in your post.  It normally helps if you also post what your code does wrong.

Comment: Read the documentation for the `for` statement. Then once it is syntactically correct, step through it with a debugger watching what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually create the images inside the loop to get five images, otherwise you only get one image, that you append five times, but it's still just one single image

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    $("<img />", {
        src   : 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg',
        width : 10,
        alt   : 'new name'
    }).appendTo('body');
}
```

Also note that jQuery can take the attributes/properties directly when constructing elements

Comment: Surely you meant `;` instead of `,` in the for loop?